# Memory leak objc_msgSend

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

I've been searching for memory leaks on my code and right now I'm really confused. I have a simple animation which I wrote manually, which seems to be the cause of the leaks. I ran Instruments attached to my process and for each generation I ran the animation once. It seems that sometimes it leaks, others, it doesn't. Take a look:

[image]

I've been trying to debug generations with large leaks (like D), but then decided to focus on smaller ones first (like E). I though that if my code is causing a leak it should be there. Well, here's generation E:

[image]

All culprits seem to boil down to the same thing: `objc_msgSend`. This function, however, is the one [responsible for calling functions](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/10/30/objc_explain_objc_msgSend_stret.html), so how can that possibly leak??

This makes me think that this might be more normal than I though. Is this the standard memory behaviour for iOS apps? Should I be looking into D instead?

Best.

Comment: you probably need to show some code.  if you're using ARC, be careful of circular references.  If you remove your custom/manual animation, does the problem go away?

Comment: every method call are done through objc_msgSend...

Comment: @NG I'm not really asking where the leak is, but rather how to find it. What I'm confused about is why are these leaks even there? Notice the stack trace, there isn't one single function written by me.

Comment: @BryanChen, I know, that's why I'm asking this. I can't make sense of it.